# Solution For Avoiding For Loop in Current For Loop using JavaScript Objects Here

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here I have 3 arrays,

- orderdIds: It contains all ordersIds
- associatedUsers: It contains all associated users to the orders.
- users: It contains all user details.

Now I have to SET the user's data into the **associatedUsers** variable. So how can I do that in a single loop? Here I try with multiple loops below

```
const orderIds = [101, 102];
const associatedUsers = [{ orderId: 101, userIds: [1, 2] }, { orderId: 102, userIds: [2] }];
const users = [{ userId: 1, email: 'email1' }, { userId: 2, email: 'email2' }];

associatedUsers.map((user) => {
    user.userIds.map((u, index) => {
        const userIndex = users.findIndex((use) => { return u === use.userId; });
        console.log(userIndex)
        if (userIndex > -1) {
            user.userIds[index] = users[userIndex]
        }
    })
});

console.log(associatedUsers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is fundamentally an operation that requires nested iterations. Talking it through in English, what you have to do is: *For each "associated user", iterate through the `userIds` and find the matching user.* So the nested loop is the only real way to go.

There is a way to decrease the computational complexity by an order of magnitude, though, from `O(n * m)` (`n`: total number of `userIds` in all arrays, `m`: total number of users) to `O(m) + O(n)`. Turn the `users` array into an object indexed by `userId` first, and then you'll be able to avoid the `.findIndex` and just look up the ID on the object.

```js
const orderIds = [101, 102];
const associatedUsers = [{ orderId: 101, userIds: [1, 2] }, { orderId: 102, userIds: [2] }];
const users = [{ userId: 1, email: 'email1' }, { userId: 2, email: 'email2' }];

const usersById = Object.fromEntries(
  users.map(
    user => [user.userId, user]
  )
);
for (const aUser of associatedUsers) {
    aUser.userIds = aUser.userIds.map(id => usersById[id] ?? id);
}

console.log(associatedUsers);
```

Comment: OP's was O(n3). isnt it O(n2) now or im i missing something

Comment: if `associatedUsers` is `n` and `users` is m `userIds` can have worst case `m`. so in the second for loop with map inside isn't it O(n*m)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I like `n * m` for a similar reason to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031036 - it makes it clearer that the time required results from a *combination* of the total IDs and the total users, which are separate collections. (yeah, operations being done on just one collection should use only an `n` for that collection - but that's not what's happening here)

Answer (score 1):

First we create a user map, which allows us to find a user by his id, without needing to loop through the whole users array every time we do so.

Then for every association we create a users array and for each userId value we get the user from the map and add it to the users array.

As such, this works in one for loop, but technically it's still 2 loops since inside the for loop we have the `.map` which loops through `associtaion.userIds`.

It can't be simplified nor optimized further.

```js
const orderIds = [101, 102];
const associatedUsers = [{ orderId: 101, userIds: [1, 2] }, { orderId: 102, userIds: [2] }];
const users = [{ userId: 1, email: 'email1' }, { userId: 2, email: 'email2' }];

const userMap = new Map(users.map(user => [user.userId, user]));
for (const association of associatedUsers) {
    association.users = association.userIds.map(userId => userMap.get(userId));
}
console.log(associatedUsers);
```